# How to take derivative with respect to logarithmic function

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives

I'm having a little bit of trouble trying to get my head around the following problem.

I have this main function

$$S_n(\alpha, \beta) = \dfrac{dV}{V} \dfrac{\alpha}{d\alpha} = \dfrac{4 \alpha  \beta^n}{(1 + \alpha)^2 - (1-\alpha)^2\beta^{2 n}}$$

The author explains that "For all values of $\alpha$, the logarithm of $S$ is, asymptotically for small $\beta$, linearly related to the logarithm of $\beta$. Thus, the slope can be determined by:

$$\dfrac{d \ln S}{d ln \beta}$$

From my understanding, I approached this problem by substituting $ln(x)$ using

$$\dfrac{d \ln(x)}{dx} = 1/ x \Rightarrow d \ln (x) = \dfrac{dx}{x} $$

Therefore, the slope would be obtained using:

$$ \dfrac{dS}{d \beta} \dfrac{\beta}{S}$$

But I'm not sure if this approach is correct, as so far it hasn't got me close to the results of the author.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $\beta$ small we have

$$S_n(\alpha, \beta) =  \dfrac{4 \alpha  \beta^n}{ (1 + \alpha)^2 - (1-\alpha)^2\beta^{2 n}}
\sim\frac{4\alpha}{(1 + \alpha)^2}\beta^n $$

then

$$\log S\sim n\log \beta+\log \left(\frac{4\alpha}{(1 + \alpha)^2 }\right)$$

and the slope should be $n$.